code conflict with two buttons - read more in Woocommerce Descriptions and display content from another post
I have two buttons on my Single Product template, a Read More for the product description in the Product details block (Wordpress theme 2024) and a second that takes the content from a custom post type and displays it when pressed called show composer. This last looks at the contents of an ACF field, matches it against the title of the custom post and displays the content. It does not show if there is no match. A conflict occurs only when the Show Composer button is displayed. The conflict prevents the Read More button from working. To confirm, if there is no Composer found that button does not appear and the Read More button works as expected. If a composer is found the Read More button fails. The only thing I can see that might cause this is that the last line of the Read More code might conflict with a line in the Show Composer code that calls the_content().
But I cant see how to resolve this if it is
The code for the two modules is below.
/*======================================================================================

#6 Shorten product long description with read more button

=======================================================================================*/

function filter_the_content( $content ) {

    // Only for single product pages

    if( ! is_product() ) return $content;

    // Set the limit of words

    $limit = 25;

    // Strip p tags if needed

    $content = str_replace( array( '<p>', '</p>' ), '', $content );

    // If the content is longer than the predetermined limit

    if ( str_word_count( $content, 0 ) > $limit ) {

        // Returns an associative array, where the key is the numeric position of the word inside the string and the value is the actual word itself

        $arr = str_word_count( $content, 2 );

        // Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

        $pos = array_keys( $arr );

        // First part

        $text = '<p>' . substr( $content, 0, $pos[$limit] ) . '<span id="dots">...</span>';

        // More part

        $text .= '<span id="more">' . substr( $content, $pos[$limit] ) . '</span></p>';

        // Read button

        $text .= '<button id="read-button"></button>';

        $content = force_balance_tags( $text ); // needded

    }

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {

            // Settings

            var read_more_btn_txt = 'Read more';

            var read_less_btn_txt = 'Read less';

            // Selectors

            var more = '#more';

            var read_button = '#read-button';

            var dots = '#dots';

            // On load

            $( more ).hide();

            $( read_button ).html( read_more_btn_txt );

            // On click

            $( read_button ).on( 'click', function() {

                if ( $( more ).is( ':hidden' ) ) {

                    $( more ).show();

                    $( dots ).hide();

                    $( read_button ).html( read_less_btn_txt );

                } else {

                    $( more ).hide();

                    $( dots ).show();

                    $( read_button ).html( read_more_btn_txt );

                }

            });

        });

    </script>

    <?php

    return $content;

}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content', 10, 1 );

/*==============================================================

# Create Show Composer Button

================================================================*/

// Function to handle the 'composer_info' shortcode

function display_composer_info() {

    global $post;

    // Unique ID for the composer content div

    $unique_id = 'composer-info-' . $post->ID;

    // Get the 'composer' ACF field value of the current product

    $composer_name = get_field('composer', $post->ID);

    // WP_Query arguments to find the 'Composers' post with the matching title

    $args = array(

        'post_type' => 'composers',

        'title'     => $composer_name,

        'posts_per_page' => 1

    );

    // The Query

    $composer_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Start output buffering to return the content

    ob_start();

    // Check if any posts were found

    if ($composer_query->have_posts()) {

        while ($composer_query->have_posts()) {

            $composer_query->the_post();

            // Button to toggle the display of the composer info

            echo '<button id="show_composer" class="show_composer" onclick="toggleComposerInfo(\'' . $unique_id . '\')">Composer Info</button>';

            // Div to contain the composer post content, hidden by default

            echo '<div id="' . $unique_id . '" style="display:none;">';

            // Display the content of the composer post

            the_content();

            echo '</div>';

        }

    } else {

        // No posts found, so no button or content is displayed

        echo '';

    }

    // Restore original Post Data

    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Get the buffered content

    $output = ob_get_clean();

    // Return the content

    return $output;

}

// Register the shortcode with WordPress

add_shortcode('composer_info', 'display_composer_info');

// Add inline JavaScript for the toggle function

function composer_info_scripts() {

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleComposerInfo(id) {

        var content = document.getElementById(id);

        content.style.display = (content.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';

    }

    </script>

    <?php

}

add_action('wp_footer', 'composer_info_scripts');


Do you have any JavaScript-related error messages in the browser console?

the_content(); will apply the registered filters, so I am guessing the issue could be that your "composer" content also gets a "read more" button applied - and then you'd have an issue with duplicate IDs on your page.

THere's no errors in the console and I've given the two buttons separate IDs in the code.

the problem appears to be related to the last line in the Read More code,a"add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content', 10, 1 );" If "the_content" changes to a unique value the button doesn't show. Would get_content work in the Show Composer button?

Answering myself, no it won't.

so add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content', 10, 1 ); conflicts with  echo '<div id="' . $unique_id . '" style="display:none;">';             the_content();  How can we resolve this?

Also please note the Composer div has a $unique_id ID so that shouldn't conflict with the Read More container.

You could use get_the_content, that doesn't apply the filters ... but that would probably only make sense, if your composer content doesn't need any of them applied to begin with.

Simple answer in the end.
I created an ACF field in the Composer Post type called Biography and moved the Description there. Then in the Show Composer Button code
the_content();

becomes
$biography = get_field('biography', $composer_post->ID); // Get the biography field value
echo $biography; // Display the biography content

and everything works fine.
